# GLSL reusable/shared functions, shared constants (OpenGL ES 2.0)?

Tags: glsl, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

*Short:*

Can I define a function that every shader can use?
Or I have to define it per shader?

---

*The whole story:*

- I want to create numerous shaders intended to colorize the input fragments with predefined gradient ramps (something like this - http://www.thinkboxsoftware.com/storage/krakatoa-support-images/krakatoa15_kcm_densitybyage_gradientrampmap.png).
- I want to define a gradient ramp **constant for each shader** (an array of vec4 color samples, where the alpha value holds the gradient position, see Pos in the picture above)
- And I need **a function** that can return a color sample from the given gradient ramp for a particular texture coordinate position.

So the ramps need to be **defined ONCE per shader**, and the function should be **defined *all at once*** that every shader can use safely.

I have the algorithms, the question is for **sharing functions, and define constants in GLSL.**

Is this possible?
Or I have to copy the function into every shader? Is there some precompile option at least?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do that similarly as in C - you declare functions in headers and define it in common C file.

In GLSL you'll need to do following:

1. in some shader (string) you define function (lets call it COMMON):

   ```
   float getCommonValue() { return 42; }
   ```
2. in all shaders you want to use this function you only declare it and use it (lets call it SHADER1):

   ```
   float getCommonValue();
   void main() { gl_Color = vec4(getCommonValue(), 0, 0, 0); }
   ```
3. when compiling shaders with `glCompileShader` you compile COMMON shader only once and store shader GLuint somewhere
4. when you link program with `glLinkProgram` for SHADER1 you attach to program with `glAttachShader` both shaders - COMMON and SHADER1. Thus you'll be able to call `getCommonValue` function from one shader to other.
5. you can reuse COMMON shader GLuint value multiple times for different sahder programs (SHADER1, SHADER2, ...).

Comment: Whoa, sounds nice, I'll try it.

Comment: What should the type of the `COMMON` shader be when we create the shader?

Comment: I have the same question as @UltimatePea. Should the shared shader be vertex, fragment, or does it not matter?

Comment: I haven't tried this but the [ES 2.0 spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf) states `Multiple shader objects of the same type may not be attached to a single program object`.